# Shrunk virtual disk file, now reported file size doesn't match

Tags: filesystems, zfs, sparse-files

I originally had a single virtual disk file (.qcow2) of roughly 3.5 TiB and I decided to "group" all similar data on its own virtual disk file, for various reasons. Obviously that meant I could shrink the original disk file (to 900 GiB) but `ls`, `stat` and friends still list the original 3.5 TiB:

```
$ ls -lhks mydisk.qcow2 
722G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.5T Aug  6 18:06 mydisk.qcow2
```

Of course I shrunk the filesystem itself (ext4) and sparsified the file afterwards, which is why only 722 GiB is currently allocated. But my backup tools also still detect 3.5 TiB and so will scan it all while the disk itself is only capable of holding 900 GiB, meaning it takes almost 4 times longer to finish than it has to.

How can I "refresh" the reported sizes? This is a machine with HDDs so I'm thinking maybe the file is too fragmented and there's some stuff around the 3.5 TiB mark? But wouldn't copying the file fix that automatically (I tried and it didn't, at least)? Also, the disk file itself resides on ZFS, if that matters.

If at all possible any solution would preferably work **in-place**. Shutting down the VM using the disk for a little while is not a problem.

Comment: As I cannot see all the important info, just judging: qcow2 file can grow only, if you clear some file, even zero it, the qcow2 files does not reduce its size; the shring can be aplied to partition only, hence the "disk" size remains 3.5TB even it is the virtual disk realised by file.

Comment: @schweik What other information were you looking for? Also I actually did shrink the disk and not just the partition (using `qemu-img resize --shrink`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of ways of doing it in-place:

1. Use `zerofree [-v] /dev/vdXY` from within the **guest** VM (if Linux, which all of mine are) to find **non-zero unallocated** blocks ("deleted" stuff) and replace them with zeroes. Follow with `fallocate --dig-holes mydisk.qcow2` from the **host** to replace the zeroes with holes. Although the latter may not be necessary depending on the host's file system, I believe ZFS automatically sees that as sparse if compression is enabled.
2. Just use `virt-sparsify --in-place mydisk.qcow2` which seems to do both zeroing out and punching holes. As far as I know this does require trim/discard/unmap support in libguestfs, though. But if the version is not too ancient it should be there.

To test I created a disk of 10 GiB, added some text files, filled up the rest with `dd if=/dev/urandom` and removed this last file. `du -h` confirms `9.8G` have been allocated. Then I made some straight copies of the virtual disk and tested respectively:

1. Since I'm using ZFS compression, after only `zerofree` it's already reduced to 1173 kB (1200640 bytes). `fallocate` doesn't change a thing (expectedly).
2. Goes even further, to 875 kB (895488 bytes).

It's a little hard to tell whether it's the ZFS compression or `zerofree` that's a little inefficient for this case. But `virt-sparsify` is one command from the host and it seems to be faster too, so I'll just use that.